# What does 'cache-control' do for a page, not a static file?

Tags: cache

When I set a value for 'cache-control' for a page, does my browser cache the whole page just like js or css?

I've set 'Cache-Control:max-age=2592000, public' and monitored apache access logs. It looks like browsers do not do anything with 'Cache-Control:max-age=2592000, public'. Not only I still get '200' response, but my server has to send back data to the browsers.

When/Why should I set 'Cache-Control' for a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cache-Control` is a cache for the actual HTML page that gets displayed in the browser as linked files (css/js/etc) are handled differently.

The browser *may* obey this directive or ignore it. It simply tells the browser that the content is cachable and it's up to the browser to display the cached content rather than sending a request to the server for an updated page.

If you'd like more information, [this](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) is a good resource, as are any other things you can find by a search.

Comment: Thank you Nathan C. Do you know how to make browsers to obey 'Cache-Control' for the whole page? I've tried all the combination, but it didn't work. That's why I asked this question. Why do we use Cache-Control for a page when it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Well, it does obey if you set Cache-Control to say, `no-store`.

Comment: // Weird..still hitting the server.